# Linking C with NASM

Tags: c, assembly, nasm

I have a NASM file and a C file. How do I call a function in the C file from the NASM file? How do I call a NASM function from the C file?

Many Thanks
DD

Comment: like this: http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc9.html

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Calling assembly function from C:

C file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int a, int b);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("%d\n", add(2, 6));
  return 0;
}
```

assembly file:

```
global add

section .data

section .text

add:
    mov   eax, [esp+4]   ; argument 1
    add   eax, [esp+8]   ; argument 2
    ret
```

compiling:

```
$ nasm -f elf add.asm 
$ gcc -Wall main.c add.o 
$ ./a.out 
8
$
```

Calling C function from assembly:

C file:

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
  return a + b;
}
```

assembly file:

```
extern add
extern printf
extern exit

global _start

section .data
  format db "%d", 10, 0
section .text

_start:
    push  6
    push  2
    call  add     ; add(2, 6)

    push  eax
    push  format
    call  printf  ; printf(format, eax)

    push  0
    call exit     ; exit(0)
```

compiling:

```
$ gcc -Wall -c add.c
$ nasm -f elf main.asm 
$ ld main.o add.o -lc -I /lib/ld-linux.so.2
$ ./a.out 
8
$
```

Comment: This, of course, assumes a 32-bit platform; it won't work on 64-bit platforms

Comment: @DrewMcGowen What makes this program a 32-bit or 64 bit ?

Comment: @AbhishekSagar by default, gcc will compile to the same number of bits as what your OS is running

Comment: It won't work on 32bit because the way you pass parameters isn't the same. You don't push stuff on the stack. Instead you use the ABI and use registers as parameters.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen How can I compile this for x86_64?

Comment: @DrewMcGowen I am using `wsl` with ubuntu 20, `nasm` version 2.14.02 and `gcc` 9.4.0. I don't have on my system the file `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`, only the file `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. But when I try to compile using `nasm -f elf64`, when I try to execute the code does not work as expected

Comment: @FelipeK.Bernardino because, as someone mentioned before, the calling convention is different for 64-bit; you'll need to modify the code to use registers according to the x64 ABI

Comment: For x86-64, you also need to maintain stack alignment.  (RSP%16 == 0 before a `call`, leading to RSP%16 == 8 on entry to functions.  See [glibc scanf Segmentation faults when called from a function that doesn't align RSP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51070716))