# Linux x86-64 call nasm from C and vice-versa

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64, nasm

Edit: [this was first posted to reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/asm/comments/180sb4g/linux_x8664_call_nasm_from_c_and_viceversa/) (but got resolved here).

TL;DR [See this stack-overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24992571) that shows **separately** how to call C from nasm and vice-versa.  I would like to achieve this at the same time, i.e., C main function calls a nasm function and it in turn calls a C function.  I am unable to link these together.

E.g., here is my `main.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int64_t entry();

void printr() {
  printf("Printing random stuff.");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int64_t result = entry();
  printf("%" PRId64 "\n", result);
  return 0;
}
```

Here is my `tri_tail_rec.s`

```
        default rel
        section .text
        global entry
entry:
        mov rbx, 10             ; the "input"
    mov rax, 0
;;; tri: a tail recursive function for computing nth
;;; triangular number, where n is given in rbx.
tri:
        cmp rbx, 0
        je done
        add rax, rbx
    sub rbx, 1
        jmp tri

done:
    extern printr
    call printr
    ret
```

I tried

```bash
nasm -f elf64 -o tri_tail_rec.o tri_tail_rec.s
cc    -c -o main.o main.c
gcc main.o tri_tail_rec.o -o tri_tail_rec
```

and got a segfault.  I also tried

```bash
ld main.o tri_tail_rec.o -lc -I /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o tri_tail_rec
```

and got the warning `ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000401020`, which in turn gave me a segfault.

Further details on how I arrived at these follow.

I am learning to program in assembly (why, because it's wonderful!), and I wanted to write a project with mixed C and nasm such that both can call functions written in other.  I am only interested in getting a working solution for Linux x86-64 machines.  I could find [an example](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2021/cmsc430/a86.html) that calls a nasm function from C, like following.
This is `tri.s`

```
        global entry
        default rel
        section .text
entry:
        mov rbx, 36             ; the "input"
;;; tri: a recursive function for computing nth
;;; triangular number, where n is given in rbx.
tri:
        cmp rbx, 0              ; if rbx = 0, done
        je done
        push rbx                ; save rbx
        sub rbx, 1
        call tri                ; compute tri(rbx-1) in rax
        pop rbx                 ; restore rbx
        add rax, rbx            ; result is rbx+tri(rbx-1)
        ret
done:                           ; jump here for base case
        mov rax, 0              ; return 0
        ret
```

Next `main.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int64_t entry();

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int64_t result = entry();
  printf("%" PRId64 "\n", result);
  return 0;
}
```

Then following shell commands to compile, link, and run the executable; this also worked on my machine without issues.

```bash
nasm -f elf64 -o tri.o tri.s
gcc -c main.c -o main.o
gcc main.o tri.o -o tri
./tri
```

So far so good.  Then I wanted to call C from assembly and found the solution on the stack-overflow link I mentioned earlier.

Comment: It's not linking that's the problem (you used `gcc` correctly), it's stack alignment.  (And also modifying call-preserved registers without saving/restoring).  `call printr` / `ret` could be a tailcall with `jmp printr`; on entry to your function, the stack is correctly aligned for entry to other functions as well, pointing at a return address with `RSP%16 == 8`.  But it's not correctly aligned for a `call` that will push another 8-byte return address.

Comment: `;;; tri: a recursive function for computing nth...` nope, your code just uses a loop.  Looks like that comment is left over from https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2021/cmsc430/a86.html where they have a recursive function that's "called" by `entry:` falling into it as an optimized tailcall.  It eventually returns to `entry`'s caller.  It's weird that they don't comment on that fall-through.  It's pretty non-obvious, especially when they didn't use a local label like `.done:` to make it more clear that `done:` is part of `tri` rather than `entry`.  `entry` modifies call-preserved RBX.

Comment: The ultimate problem is [glibc scanf Segmentation faults when called from a function that doesn't align RSP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51070716) (which applies to `printf` as well in modern builds of glibc, even with no FP args.)  The top of my answer there explains the ABI requirement in general, so it applies to calling any C function, including your `printr()`.  A debugger (like `gdb`) should show you where your program segfaulted.  I could close this as a duplicate, but perhaps its worthwhile to have an answer that puts all the puzzle pieces together into a working example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed comments!  I have read them, and I'll respond soon with my progress.

Comment: Re: registers, [What registers are preserved through a linux x86-64 function call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18024672) / [What are callee and caller saved registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56178078)

Comment: Thanks again, Peter, for your prompt help! You're doing noble work.

Apparently I had two problems that you mentioned.  Stack wasn't aligned to 16-byte boundary, and my return value in `rax` was being overwritten by `printr` call.  I managed to solve both of these issues by adding `push rax` before `call printr` and `pop rax` after.  I think you should close this as a duplicate if you'd like.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the feedback that those links were helpful to a beginner.  That was my goal when writing my answers there, but it's hard to know when I might be assuming other background knowledge that some beginners might not have, resulting in explanations that are hard to follow.

Comment: Indeed very helpful links, but as a fan of a linear narrative, I sense a lack of a textbook on these matters.  If you write one, I will definitely buy!

Comment: I do own a physical copy of [Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective](https://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/), but that does not contain the whole story and it's a tome.